# Syntax for OR expressions in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, dataset, logical-or

I do not know Visual Basic as much as I know C++ or C#.

I'm going to check if a select query have any results in returned 'testDataset` and have some results, so I wrote below syntax:

```
If ((testDataset Is Nothing) Or (testDataset.Tables Is Nothing) Or testDataset.Tables.Count = 0 _
    Or (testDataset.Tables.Item(0).Rows Is Nothing) Or (testDataset.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Count = 0) _
    Or (testDataset.Tables.Item(0).Rows(0) Is Nothing)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Dataset has no results!", "Database Query Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return False
End If
```

In C++ when an expression inside logical OR comes true next expression will not be processed. But it seems this is not the case in Visual Basic. So I want to know how can I check several expressions in visual basic and stop processing next ones if one came true.

So my question is mainly can be asked as two questions:

1. How can I check several condition's using OR without processing next ones?
2. How can I check if Dataset has results (at least one row) and an specific column is present in that (at least one) row?

Comment: You're probably looking for [OrElse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/orelse-operator) and [AndAlso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator)

Comment: While you mention C++, it's not really relevant to the problem itself so I removed the C++ language tag.

Comment: And the term you're looking for is [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It might help you find better hits when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to short circuit all those checks in one line. The `?` after the member in this chain will stop evaluating subsequent members and return null if the member is null.

```vb
Return testDataset?.Tables?.Item(0)?.Rows?.Any() ' true if any, false if none
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea to several checks (+1). The question is why DataSet an be null or Tables(0) can be null, etc.  I'm pretty sure that simply `try-catch` block is enough.

Comment: @MaciejLos I have learned to use exception handling sparingly, either to ensure that your app won't crash (catch-all) or for a specific Exception such as `UnauthorizedAccessException` etc., and whenever possible, not to incorporate it into the logic of your program. An Exception is exceptional, and shouldn't be considered normal. Of course, your approach will work... But I just saw OP's logic as something which could be simplified with some elegant syntax. Thanks for the +1

Comment: @MaciejLos Right? So keeping the null checks in the logic, it's clear what is going on here, while a `Try...Catch` replaces and obfuscates the logic. This is more of a best practice distinction, and maybe a little too philosophical for the OP :)

Comment: I was trying to say that i'd never write a code which returns unknown result. When a function written by me returns null (nothing) i do it intentionally... I can't agree with "illogical logic" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This - probably - is not an exact answer, but general advice...

The shortest way to catch error while reading data from dataset is to get a code into [Try...Catch..Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) block.

```
Dim bRetVal As Boolean = True
Try
   'your code to read data
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong..." & vbCrLf  & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error while reading data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    bRetVal = False
Finally
  Return bRetVal
```

Answer (score 1):

This is overkill on checking for `Nothing`. Presumably you have created a `DataSet` and filled it with a `DataTable`. The table may not have any rows returned but neither the `DataSet` nor the `DataTable` is Nothing.

If you are only using a single table, then dispense with the DataSet.

```
Private dt As New DataTable

Private Sub GetData()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConLocal),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 10 * From Coffees", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function CheckTable() As Boolean
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return True
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Dataset has no results!", "Database Query Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Since there might be many unpredictable occasions (such as a table which its columns might not be as expected,...), so I'm not sure that e.g. column `x` is present in table so it might be the situation that all these checks are necessary (I guess!)

Comment: @VSB I am sure you have a point. In this code, the schema is determined by the result set so no problem with added or missing columns. I understand DBA's can make breaking changes occasionally.